# SAS Macro Conditional Equal returning error

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have two numeric variables, date1 and date2, which are both currently set to 20170502.

In my macro, I want to send an email if the two variables are equal. This is my code:

```
%let date1 = input(put(intnx('day', today(),-3),yymmddn8.),8.); 
%macro EMAIL;
filename INSRNC email;
data _null_;  
%if &date1. = &date2. %then %do; 
file INSRNC to="email@address"
subject= "test";
put "email message";
%end; 
run; 
%mend;
%EMAIL;
```

I am getting the error message: "Required operator not found in expression"

Am I using the wrong operator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If these are defined macro variables, then this should work as you posted it.  I would recommend making a modification; you should pass `date1` and `date2` as parameters, even if they are just passed as is, due to the principle of encapsulation.  But what you posted would work, just based on global macro variables.

```
%let date1=20140101;
%let date2=20140101;
%macro EMAIL(date1=, date2=);
filename INSRNC email;
data _null_;  
%if &date1. = &date2. %then %do; 
  *file INSRNC to="email@address"
subject= "test";
  put "email message";
%end; 
run; 
%mend;

%EMAIL(date1=&date1., date2=&date2.);
```

If you're getting `required operator not found in expression` then your macro variables are not correctly defined and may have a character in them that is making this fail to read properly.  Use `OPTIONS MPRINT SYMBOLGEN;` to see why.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually defining date1 = input(put(intnx('day', today(),-3),yymmddn8.),8.); 
When I used OPTIONS MPRINT SYMBOLGEN, I found that it was interpreting date1 as "input(put(intnx('day', today(),-3),yymmddn8.),8.)" instead of by calling the actual date. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @CahnEx `%let date1 = %sysfunc(sum(%sysfunc(today()),-3),yymmddn8.); %put &date1;`  You need to wrap any dataset functions within a call to `%sysfunc()` if you want the functions to actually resolve - otherwise they will be treated just like any other string to the macro language.  Consider the following for a simple example of this concept: `%let date1 = date(); %let date2 = %sysfunc(date()); %put &=date1 &=date2;`

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

@Joe gave a perfect explanation on how to define macros. Passing the macros as parameters makes it far easy. However, looking at your comment on how `date1` is getting resolved, please see the below

```
date1 = %sysfunc(input(put(intnx('day', today(),-3),yymmddn8.),8.));
```

Kindly read through the importance of [%Sysfunc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514sysfunc.htm) in resolving macros to have a better understanding.

Comment: The put function is superfluous - look at using the second optional parameter of `%sysfunc()` instead to apply a format to the value before it is returned by `%sysfunc()`